# Change selected item from select2 with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use jquery to select the value of the desired item from select2.When I manually write the following code, it works correctly.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<select class="form-control select2" id="voip">
    <option value="101001001">A</option>
    <option value="101001002">B</option>
    <option value="101001003">C</option>
    <option value="101001004">D</option>
</select>

$('#voip').val('101001003').trigger('change');
```

But when I receive the desired value with Ajax, it does not work.
Please guide me, thank you

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"ajax_voip.php?internal=1",
    method:"GET",
    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#voip').val(data).trigger('change'); 
        alert(data);//this ok return 101001003
     }
})
```

Comment: Sorry voip should be

Comment: Try `console.log("[" + data + "]")` to ensure there's no extra spaces that `alert()` won't show.  Don't use `alert()` for debugging.  Or, of course, just `$('#voip').val((""+data).trim()).trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible your ajax call is returning a number and not a string...
try:

```
$('#voip').val((""+data).trim()).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code did not work either. I even stringed the id and sent a string from ajax, but it didn't work

Comment: can you put the your code, including the html in a js fiddle or codepen?

Comment: i haven't used jquery in a while

Comment: ok André Alçada Padez
I will post it as soon as possible, thank you